# Couchbase N1QL query running, but no data retrieved (wrong query i guess)

Tags: join, couchbase, bucket, sql++, nosql

I am trying to retrieve data from 2 buckets, no error but nothing shows up (I do have documents I need in these buckets).

1st bucket: a_bucket

here is the document I am interested in (I do have 3 different docs)

author_ID document:

```
{
"author_ID": 1,
"profil_creation_date": "2017/01/01/01:23:05/+5",
"prefix": "Mr.",
"first_name": "Dylan",
"middle_name_s": "Alfred",
"last_name": "Kerr",
"date_of_birth": "1974/01/02",
"sex": "M",
"marital_status": "Single",
"mobile_phone": "(860) 231-3336",
"address": [
{
"address_1": {
"address_ID": 1,
"home_address": "338 Counts Lane",
"city": "West Hartford",
"province/state": "CT",
"postal_code": "06105"
}
},
{
"address_2": {
"address_ID": 2,
"work_address": "977 Copperhead Rd",
"city": "Newington",
"province/state": "CT",
"postal_code": "06111"
}
}
]
}
```

2nd bucket: b_bucket

here are the 2 docs I am interested in:

p_output_ID document:

```
{
"p_output_ID": 1,
"author_ID": 2,
"overall_score": 4.41,
"status": {
"r_status_first": "TRUE",
"r_status_second": "FALSE",
"r_status_third": "YES",
"y_status_second": "TRUE",
"y_status_third": "FALSE",
"g_status_third": "TRUE"
}
}
```

timing_ID document:

{

```
"timing_ID": 1,
"p_output_ID": 1,
"author_ID": 1,
"date_and_time": "2017-06-06/23:45:25.25/+5",
"time_in_seconds": 12525,
"incremental_time_in_seconds": "time_in_seconds",
"current_state_and_duration": {
"state": "RED",
"duration_in_seconds": 33333
}
}
```

my goal is to grab these informations in one query ():

prefix, first_name, middle_name_s, last_name (from author_ID document in a_bucket)
overall_score (from p_output_ID document in b_bucket)
date_and_time, state (from timing_ID document in b_bucket)

Here is my query:

```
select p2.current_state_and_duration.state, p1.overall_score, p2.date_and_time 
from proc_data_bucket p1 USE KEYS "p_output_ID" 
JOIN proc_data_bucket p2 ON KEYS "author_ID";
```

The syntax is OK, but I am getting no data

Please help me with that...

Comment: This has been answered in couchbase forums https://forums.couchbase.com/t/querying-documents-from-2-different-buckets-help/13594/2

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON b_bucket(timing_ID);
SELECT p1.prefix, p1.first_name, p1.middle_name_s, p1.last_name,
       p2.date_and_time,p2.state,
       p3.overall_score
  FROM b_bucket p2
  JOIN a_bucket p1 ON KEYS ("author_" || TO_STRING(p2.author_ID))
  JOIN b_bucket p3 ON KEYS ("p_output_" || TO_STRING(p2.p_output_ID))
WHERE p2.timing_ID BETWEEN 10 AND 50;
```